# Creating new instances of a class at different addresses

Tags: c++, class, pointers, instance

I'm rather new to c++. I have been programming Java for quite some time so i apologize in advance if i use some java terminology instead of the proper c++ terminology.

I want to create a hash map(`unordered_map`) which maps `int` to pointers to a class. Now the trouble for me is to create "new" instances of the class at different addresses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
using namespace std;

class paul{
    public:
        paul(int n) {stuff = n;}
        int stuff;
};

int main(void) {
    tr1::unordered_map<int,paul*> glenn;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        paul victor(i*i);
        glenn[i] = &victor;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << i*i << "," << (*glenn[i]).stuff << "\n";
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The code above does not work. It produces the output:

```
0,16
1,16
4,16
9,16
16,16
```

This is due to the fact that each new instance of `paul` gets created at the same address and thus every key in `glenn` will map to the same instance of `paul`.

So my question is now this how can i create several instances of a class at different  addresses?

Comment: *Why* do you want to store pointers in your map? BTW the problem is that you are storing dangling pointers.

Comment: Because i don't want to store the entire object in the map. Or does `unordered_map` do this automatically?
It only stores one pointer and that is still refering to an object so it shouldn't be dangling. If i have understood how dangling pointers work.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to store the object in the map? Your pointers are dangling because the object they point to ceases to exist immediately.

Comment: @HenrikSommerland: Where else do you want to save it? In nirvana, because that's where you save it now?

Comment: No when i think of it i have no reason not to. I was just being a bit thick. Since i wont have any other collection of the same objects somewhere else i can just as well always keep them in the map.

Comment: Just for the record, if you really did need to store pointers, then you'd need to allocate the `paul`s as `paul* victor = new paul(i*i);`. And then you'd need to remember to `delete` each and every one at some later point. `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` can save you the cleanup work, but they're doing the same thing under the hood.

Comment: A good reason to at least keep in mind that you might want to store pointers would be if you kept a hash map of base classes that you wanted to use polymorphically. If `paul` ever has children that you want to store in the same hash map you may need to store them as pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is now this how can i create several instances of a class at different addresses?

Forget about addresses and pointers, and store objects:

```
tr1::unordered_map<int, paul> glenn;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    glenn[i] = paul(i*i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store pointers in your map, allocate them on the heap to extend their lifetime and prefer to use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`
(these smart pointers require the use of C++11 or higher).

The heap allocation will store each `new`ly created object at a different address in memory on the heap. The smart pointers will clean up the objects when they're lifetime is up (a primitive form of garbage collection).

```
int main(void) {
    tr1::unordered_map<int,std::unique_ptr<paul>> glenn;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        glenn[i].reset(new paul(i*i)); // prefer to use std::make_unique if/when it is available.
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << i*i << "," << (*glenn[i]).stuff << "\n";
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: In this case, the `std::unique_ptr`s get cleaned up when `glenn` goes out of scope.